# Download code from Google App Engine Java is now possible - Ubuntu

Tags: java, google-app-engine

According to Google's AppEngine Group using the pre-released version 1.5.3 you are able to download you code for Java Applications as well.

```
./appcfg.sh help download_app
AppCfg [options] -A app_id [ -V version ] download_app <out-dir>

Download a previously-uploaded app to the specified directory.  The app
ID is specified by the "-A" option.  The optional version is specified
by the "-V" option.
```

I tried to run the above command but it is not working.

Did anyone manage to download his/her source code using the above command?

Thanks

The changelog:

> AppCfg now supports download_app, which will download all files that were
>   uploaded from your war directory.

Comment: What command exactly are you running, and what error message are you getting?

Comment: The paragraph you quoted was from the "pre-release" not the actual release, I'm not sure if that made it into "release"... you can however still use the Python version to download your java source

Comment: Can you post an example please? I run `./appcfg.sh –A myappname download_app /home/myusername/code` but it's not working.I also tried  -v but still not working.

Comment: @Immo "It's not working" is about the least helpful error report possible. What happens when you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it works with the pre-release SDK. I just tried it:

```
$ mkdir /path/to/my/backup/dir
$ ./appcfg.sh -A myappid download_app /path/to/my/backup/dir
```

Or defining a version:

```
$ ./appcfg.sh -A myappid -V 2 download_app /path/to/my/backup/dir
```

I downloaded a Python and a Java app, and both worked.

Answer (score 0):

On the Developer website it gives this code :
[Google-Developer](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Downloading_an_Application)

```
/appcfg.sh download_app -A <your_app_id> -V <your_app_version> <output-dir>
```

I tried it didn't work. On some articles `download_app` comes before `<output-dir>`

So I tried like this and it works fine :

```
/appcfg.sh -A <your_app_id> -V <your_app_version> download_app <output-dir>
```