# Is there any way to view the WAR file deployed to Google AppEngine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Is there any way to inspect the WAR file that I have deployed to GAE?  I want to verify that the structure and content is correct when troubleshooting system config and replication issues.

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10828693/227646 Specifically, the answer points to App Engine documentation where you can see [sample code](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Downloading_an_Application). Please note that an admin may have blocked download access. In this case, you cannot get the web archive out of App Engine. "After you prohibit code download, there is no way to re-enable this feature."

Comment: Ick, I have to download it?  They should have a simple browser...  oh well, thanks!